# IE9 does not execute Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-9

Seems like a fairly common problem, but after searching trough a stack of SO posts I'm still no closer, so here we go.

IE9 refuses to execute my ajax call, it skips straight to the error function. No request is sent from the browser and no error is given in console, which makes the problem all that much harder to debug.

I'm guessing the problem is very specific to IE9 as it works in Chrome, FF and even IE8.
The POST request is cross domain, but fortunately I can modify whatever headers I want if someone thinks that will help.

*Note that I use polyfill for console.log(), even though as far as I know that should only affect < IE8.*

**What I've tried**

- Adding cache:false
- Adding timestamp
- Adding contentType
- Sawing my computer in half

**Code**

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:
        'http://mydomain.com/api/path/' + someVar +
        '/additional/parameter/paths' +
        '?ts=' + new Date().getTime(),
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function () {
        $('#contact-form-success').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log('The request failed (XHR / Status)');
        console.log(xhr);
        console.log(status);
        $('#contact-form-error').foundation('reveal', 'open');
    },
    complete: function () {
        stopAnimateButton();
    }

});
```

Comment: the fact that it is cross domain is your problem. IE9 requires the use of the XDomainRequest object which jQuery does not use. http://caniuse.com/xhr2

Comment: Was afraid of that, with all the information available on the topic I guess it was wishful thinking that lead me to believe my problem was otherwise related.

Comment: Note, it's completely possible to do this with $.ajax and related methods, you just have to add a new transport or a prefilter that implements the XDomainRequest object. https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest in IE7 CORS simply isn't possible other than through script includes (such as jsonp)

Comment: Thanks a lot, MoonScript did the trick. Given that this question doesn't get closed as a duplicate, I'd be more then happy to accept your latest comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IE8 and 9 require the use of the `XDomainRequest` object to perform cross-domain requests using CORS. IE7 does not support CORS at all.

jQuery does not implement the `XDomainRequest` due to various inconsistencies.

To get around this, you basically need to re-write how cross-domain requests are handled, either by not using jQuery, or adding a transport to jQuery that intercepts all cross-domain requests and handles them in a way that uses `XDomainRequest` when available, and xhr2 otherwise.

This question shows how to do it without using `$.ajax`:
[Why does this cross-domain request work in other browsers but not IE9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6435277/why-does-this-cross-domain-request-work-in-other-browsers-but-not-ie9)

And here's a github repo that shows how to instead add the transport.
https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

If you need IE7 support, you'll have to either use JSONP, or a server-side proxy.